# When trying to link an OpenMP program on OS X ld returns an error

Tags: macos, 64-bit, openmp, linker-errors

I am currently working on an OpenMP program running both on Linux (openSUSE 12.2) and OS X (10.8.1), both x86_64. Linking is no problem on Linux, on OS X however I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_gomp_tls_key", referenced from:
      _GOMP_barrier in libgomp.a(barrier.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/resolma_t] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/resolma_t.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How do I fix this? g++ is invoked with -fopenmp so this obviously can't be the reason. My gcc version is `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2`, other OpenMP programs link and work perfectly on the same machine.

Comment: Openmp is implemented since gcc 4.2. Your failure only suggests that the library is not build correctly. Try Downloading the new version or rebuild the same and follow [TO DO LIST](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/openmp)

Comment: alternatively you can use CLANG with CLAGN-OMP - http://clang-omp.github.io/ which is more Mac way